# How to change the default terminal prompt location to the right side?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell

Basically i need to know how to switch the default side of the prompt on (linux) terminal (which is on the left side of the screen normally).

I don't think anyone else attempted this, or even thought of this (probably because it is kinda useless on its own). 
But i'm still curious to know how to do it, whether by just editing part of said terminal(s) (in this context its mostly on linux, don't have a specific for terminal but xterm would do) 
or by some alteration on the PS1 variable in the shell(s) (whatever shells would do, bonus if its bash or posix compliant?)

EDIT: here a rough draft i made on draw.io (thanks Attie for the suggestion)

[image: draft]

Comment: Are you trying to do this for [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) input, or because it looks "_cool_"? How do you envision it to working if not RTL? Can you share a diagram or similar? I'm not sure that RTL is going to be sensible on the command line... I've never hear of it, and I can imagine it raising lots of further issues with cursor placement, etc... Editors can be set to RTL mode (like [`vim`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/rileft.html), though it's not supported by default in Ubuntu's package).

Comment: If you just want to put the prompt at the far-right edge of the screen, such that your input will immediately wrap to the next line, try `PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=$(printf "%*s" $(tput cols) "\$")'`

Comment: Check out `zsh` and its `RPROMPT` variable.

Comment: Didn't know about the exact term you used (here in this case RTL) but it is similar to what i wanted to do yes; although your other solution seems to work fine for the prompt itself, if it could write the character on the opposite side too to "mirror" the normal way a terminal work, it would be better.
(btw, i can make a diagram/add more detail on how i envision it, but not sure if i should just edit my post above or make another one) @Attie

Comment: Yeah, it does look easier to do what i want in zsh it seems, but i would have preferred if it was done in bash, or something posix compliant (that work on bash/sh/other shells) @egmont

Comment: "_write the character on the opposite side too to "mirror" the normal way a terminal work, it would be better_" it sounds like you're expecting RTL input (i.e: not English)... I can't comment on how well this will work with anything on the command line, sorry.

Comment: Please use a tool like [draw.io](https://draw.io) to make a diagram (step by step), and then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1499174/edit) your question to include the additional details... you may need to include a link to the image (use imgur) and someone with more reputation can inline the image for you.

Comment: Done, thanks a lot for the suggestion @Attie, didn't knew this site before.